# How to demultiplex BCL data with two different barcoding systems?

Tags: bioinformatics

I was wondering if anyone has experience in demultiplexing BCL files from Illumina with two different barcoding systems in one go?

we would like to know whether it is possible to use different, barcoded Tn5 adaptors during tagmentation and then use those Barcodes in combination with the barcodes on the sequencing primers to demultiplex the samples.

Has anyone has experience with this kind of analysis?
Is it possible to only add the Tn5 sequence to the primer sequence before demultiplexing and use it in the BCL2fastq run?

thanks

Assa

Comment: Consider posting on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very well aware of Tn5 adaptors library but I will give it a shot.
In theory, it should be possible. bcl2fastq can demultiplex anything as long as you give it a proper samplesheet and a correct `--use-bases-mask` argument.

If you need to demultiplex all samples with a combination of two barcode system, you will have to create a samplesheet with a line for each combination that can be found. You also need to know at which cycles the Tn5 adaptors are sequenced.

For example lets say my original samplesheet is like:

```
[Data]
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,Index_Plate_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description
ID-1,ID-1,,,A01,UDP0001,GAACTG,UDP0001,TCGTGG,project,
ID-2,ID-2,,,B01,UDP0002,AGGTCA,UDP0002,CTACAA,project,
```

i would use a `--use-bases-mask` argument like `Y*,I6,I6,Y*` to tell bcl2fastq that is needs to read 6 bases for the barcodes.

Now if your Tn5 adaptors are located just after your illumina barcodes, you will need a samplesheet like:

```
    [Data]
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,Index_Plate_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description
    ID-1-1,ID-1-1,,,A01,UDP0001,GAACTGATGC,UDP0001,TCGTGGATGC,project,
    ID-1-2,ID-1-2,,,A01,UDP0001,GAACTGCGAT,UDP0001,TCGTGGCGAT,project,
    ID-2-1,ID-2-1,,,B01,UDP0002,AGGTCAATGC,UDP0002,CTACAAATGC,project,
    ID-2-2,ID-2-2,,,B01,UDP0002,AGGTCACGAT,UDP0002,CTACAACGAT,project,
```

note the added 4 bases behind the (previously defined) illumina adaptors with different combinations. Here we would use a `--use-bases-mask` argument like `Y*,I10,I10,Y*`. This is a very dummy example to illustrate how bcl2fastq works.
Two major difficulties:

- You have to know all the possible combinations to put them in the samplesheet. If you have a kind of UMI barcoding (random bases), you cannot do it.
- You must know precisely at which cycles the barcodes are read to use a `--use-bases-mask` argument accordingly.

Maybe I could understand better what you're trying to achieve with an example of a samplesheet you're using and the bcl2fastq command you're running.